# TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined in child to parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I am getting the following error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined
closeAlert
```

It seems to be the bind or props issue?

So what should I do?

Main Component:

```
class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        alertOpen : false
    };

    this.closeAlert.bind(this);
}

closeAlert(event) {
    this.setState({
        closeAlert : true
    });
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <AlertWindow
closeAlert={this.closeAlert}
             />
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

Child Component:

```
    const AlertWindow = ({ closeAlert }) => {
    return (
    <Alert type="primary">

    <Button
      color="secondary"
      RootComponent="button"
      onClick={(event) => {
        closeAlert(event)
      }}
    >
      No, thanks
    </Button>
  </Button.List>
   </Alert>
  );
  };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your bind statement is not correct, change it to the following:

```
this.closeAlert = this.closeAlert.bind(this);
```

You need to assign the bound function to the class method. Bind without the assignment not enough.

Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 2):

Another easy workaround:
convert your cloaseAlert method to :

```
closeAlert=(event)=> {
  this.setState({
    closeAlert : true
  });
}
```

now you don't need the binding statement for the method in constructor

Answer (score 0):

I think you got a bit confused about the naming. You are setting `alertOpen` state.
Not quite sure what `AlertWindow` does, but you need an action that calls closeAction (like `onClick={this.closeAlert}`)

Also as @Alexander mentioned your bind was not correct.

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            alertOpen : true
        };

        this.closeAlert = this.closeAlert.bind(this);
    }

    closeAlert(event) {
        this.setState({
            alertOpen : false
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <AlertWindow
closeAlert={this.state.closeAlert}
             />
        );
    }
}
```

Your 'opens' and 'closes' were mixed up so I don't know what the initial state was supposed to be.